# extract specific part of an array

Tags: python, string, list

I have the following list

```
array = [CHR.calc.2850_00145,CHR.calc.2860_045140,CHR.calc.2870_015,CHR.calc.2880_0160]
```

I would like to have the following output list :

```
  array = [ 2850,2860,2870,2880]
```

Regards,

Comment: The list contains strings? Is the format of those strings always consistent?

Comment: yes , I will have CHR.calc. in the beginning and a reference after the _

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> array = [
...     'CHR.calc.2850_00145',
...     'CHR.calc.2860_045140',
...     'CHR.calc.2870_015',
...     'CHR.calc.2880_0160',
... ]
>>> [x.split('.')[2].split('_')[0] for x in array]
['2850', '2860', '2870', '2880']
>>> [int(x.split('.')[2].split('_')[0]) for x in array]
[2850, 2860, 2870, 2880]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [int(s[9:13]) for s in array]
# assuming the contents of array are strings all of the same format.
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a simple solution, but is very effective

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("(\d.*)_")

result = []
array = ['CHR.calc.2850_00145',
       'CHR.calc.2860_045140',
       'CHR.calc.2870_015',
       'CHR.calc.2880_0160']

for word in array:
    result.append(re.findall(pattern, word)[0])

['2850', '2860', '2870', '2880']
```